# RegularExpression put something in group (in case of OR)

Tags: ruby, regex, replace

I have grouped a number followed by a letter by this regex:

```
(\d*)(\D)
```

when number exist, result is:

```
[12,letter]
```

when there is not number, result is:

```
["",letter]
```

how can i put something instead of an empty string?
Like this:

```
(\d*|put "1")(\D)
```

Can Regex do anything of similar?

Comment: No, regex only matches what is there in the text, you cannot use it to pass any default values other than - here - empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own matching function.

```js
function matchPut(regexp, str) {
 var match = str.match(regexp);
 if(match[1] === "") {
   match[1] = "1";
 }
 return match;
}
result = matchPut(/(\d*)(\D)/,"L");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Just bear in mind that in your successful case: [12, letter], that's the integer 12, but in the default case ["1", letter], that's the string '1', not an integer; in case it matters what class the first element of the result is.